# Delete rows from a dataframe but keep rownames

Tags: r

I am using the data of the rugarch package:

```
  library(rugarch)
  data(sp500ret)
```

The data look like:

```
head(sp500ret)
               SP500RET
1987-03-10  0.008840447
1987-03-11 -0.001892734
1987-03-12  0.003129678
1987-03-13 -0.004577455
1987-03-16 -0.005742768
1987-03-17  0.014603325
```

> I just want to have the first e.g. 1000 values, so I tried

```
sp500retmod<-sp500ret[-c(1001:length(sp500ret[,1])),1]
```

But this gives

```
head(sp500retmod)

[1]  0.008840447 -0.001892734  0.003129678 -0.004577455 -0.005742768
[6]  0.014603325
```

So the rownames are deleted, how can I get the first 1000 values and keep the rowname, the date?

I also tried

```
sp500retmod<-sp500ret[-c(1001:length(sp500ret[,1])),]
```

but this does also not work.

Comment: Sorry, I made a typo.

Comment: @gung you can migrate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that both of these work:

```
d1 <- head(sp500ret, n=1000L)
rownames(d1)

d2 <- subset(sp500ret, c(1:length(SP500RET)) < 1001)
rownames(d2)

# Solution from @Penguin_Knight
d3 <- subset(sp500ret, row(sp500ret) < 1001)
rownames(d3)
```

Comment: I also have another version that works: d3 <- subset(sp500ret, row(sp500ret) < 1001)

Comment: More elegant than mine. (I didn't know about row(). You should add it as an answer.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to use the `"["` function, you can use:

```
sp500ret[seq(1000), , FALSE]
```

The `FALSE` is an argument for the `drop` parameter. The default value is `TRUE`, but this will transform a single-column data frame into a vector. Hence the row names would be lost. If you specify `FALSE`, you will receive a data frame with the original row names.